# Skip authentication with WIF and asp.net 4.5 MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, wif

I have asp.net 4.5 MVC 5 application. the authentication is implemented with WIF.The application can work with multiple identity providers, like WAAD

If i access page like https://example.com/home ; it automatically gets redirected to login page and everything works fine.

Now i want to skip all request starting with https://example.com/api  (e.g. https://example.com/api/getusers or https://example.com/api/getuserinfo/123  etc) and those should go forward.

There is no controller like api in my mvc application.

What i want to do is once these request are skipped from authentication those will be take care by arr reverse proxy to forward to another port.

I dont want to write all api path in web.config.

How can i skip the authentication.

thanks,

Subodh

Answer (score 0):

I created directory with name api in my main mvc web application.
Add web.config with following details

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>

        <authorization>
            <allow users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This skips the authentication for all calls starting with api.